# AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__' when trying to add a widget to a personalized id of Layout

Tags: python, kivy

when trying to add a widget (a layout in the problem) to a personalized id that i modify to the layout it launchs me an error that i believe that i does not identify the id personalized

```
gr_ly = GridLayout(id=i[1], rows=1)

self.LayoutGeneralCI.ids.realll.add_widget(gr_ly)

#Adding another widget to the custom id layout but just always puts me the widgets into the last layout executed

gr_ly.add_widget(self.DatosLayoutCI)
```

Here all the code

```
def selection_data_secciones(self):

    self.mainwid.dataBase = sqlite3.connect("UserData")
    self.mainwid.dataCursor = self.mainwid.dataBase.cursor()
    self.mainwid.dataCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM SECCIONES")
    fetch = self.mainwid.dataCursor.fetchall()
    for i in fetch:
        self.LayoutGeneralCI = LayoutGeneralCI(self.mainwid)  
        ref_idd = i[1]
        gr_ly = GridLayout(id=i[1], rows=1)
        print(type(gr_ly.id))
        self.LayoutGeneralCI.ids.realll.add_widget(gr_ly)
        print(self.LayoutGeneralCI.ids)
        self.LayoutGeneralCI.ids.title_sect_lbl.text = i[1]
        self.ids.container_ci.add_widget(self.LayoutGeneralCI) 
    for produ in self.mainwid.dataCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM MATERIALES"):
        self.DatosLayoutCI = DatosLayoutCI(self.mainwid)
        txtvar_ci = "Nombre: [b]{}[/b] \n".format(produ[1])
        txtvar2_ci = "Proveedor: [b]{}[/b] \n".format(produ[3])
        if produ[8] <= str(0):
            txtvar3_ci = "Disponibilidad: [color=#FF0000][b]Agotado[/b][/color]" 
        else:
            txtvar3_ci = "Disponibilidad: [color=#00FF00][b]Disponible[/b][/color]"
        txtvargeneral_ci = txtvar_ci + txtvar2_ci + txtvar3_ci
        self.DatosLayoutCI.ids.content_cill.text = txtvargeneral_ci
        var_sectttion = self.mainwid.AgregarProductos.ids.section_product.text#
        var_reference_id = produ[2]  
        gr_ly.add_widget(self.DatosLayoutCI)
    self.mainwid.dataBase.commit()   #DISCOMMENT NECCESARY
    self.mainwid.dataBase.close()
```

the results are:

```
self.LayoutGeneralCI.ids.var.add_widget(self.DatosLayoutCI)
File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 841, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Comment: You have to add more code in this question, the other question will be automatically eliminated in the future so for future readers will not understand your question, the idea is that your question will not only serve you but the community now and from the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem 2

> Kept adding DatosLayoutCI widgets to the last widget, gr_ly

## Solution

In order to display all the material (MATERIALES) under each section (SECCIONES), one has to use either one SQL statement with INNER JOIN or two SELECT statements (nested SELECTs).

### Snippets - Nested SELECTs

```
def selection_data_secciones(self):

    self.mainwid.dataBase = sqlite3.connect("UserData")
    self.mainwid.dataCursor = self.mainwid.dataBase.cursor()
    self.mainwid.dataCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM SECCIONES")  # Sections
    fetch = self.mainwid.dataCursor.fetchall()

    for i in fetch:
        self.LayoutGeneralCI = LayoutGeneralCI(self.mainwid)
        ref_idd = i[1]
        gr_ly = GridLayout(id=i[1], rows=1)
        ...

        self.mainwid.dataCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM MATERIALES WHERE id=?", (gr_ly.id))
        materials = self.mainwid.dataCursor.fetchall()

        for produ in materials:
            self.DatosLayoutCI = DatosLayoutCI(self.mainwid)    # Datos = Data
            ...    
            gr_ly.add_widget(self.DatosLayoutCI)

    self.mainwid.dataBase.commit()   #DISCOMMENT NECCESARY
    self.mainwid.dataBase.close()
```

## Problem 1

```
self.LayoutGeneralCI.ids.var.add_widget(self.DatosLayoutCI)
File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 841, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

## Reason

The ids created in Python script is different from the ids created in the kv file.

## Kivy Documentation

[Kv Language » Referencing Widgets](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets)

[Kv Language » Accessing Widgets defined inside Kv lang in your python code](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code)

## Differences

### kv file

- When assigning a value to id, remember that the value isn’t a string. There are no quotes: good -> `id: value`, bad -> `id: 'value'`
- Access it in Python script using `self.ids.realll` or `self.ids['realll']`
- When your kv file is parsed, kivy collects all the widgets tagged with id’s and places them in this `self.ids` dictionary type property. That means you can also iterate over these widgets and access them dictionary style.

### py file

- The `id` is a string
- Cannot access it using `self.ids.var`
- Not stored in `self.ids`

## Solution

```
gr_ly = GridLayout(id=str(i[1]))

#####adding a widget to the personalized id of layout

gr_ly.add_widget(self.DatosLayoutCI)

self.LayoutGeneralCI.ids.realll.add_widget(gr_ly)

#######all the code is in a function so i want to créate a layout that will #######contain the widgets with a personalized id and then calling the #######personalized id to add the widget in different and specific layouts##

####defining the layout and it's personalized id and adding to the class

gr_ly = GridLayout(id=str(i[1]))

#####adding a widget to the personalized id of layout

gr_ly.add_widget(self.DatosLayoutCI)

self.LayoutGeneralCI.ids.realll.add_widget(gr_ly)#####1 PRIMERA OPCION
```

Comment: i tried that solution but the result is the same, the specific problem is that i want to add into the personalized layout widgets that have the same id as the layout, but trying this code when i run it always insert the layout on the final layout executed, another suggestion, please help

Comment: If you are adding two `gr_ly` then you have to execute `gr_ly.add_widget(self.DatosLayoutCI)` after instantiated each `gr_ly`.

Comment: i have added more code to a better understand of the problem, pelease check it and i hope you find an answer!, thanks

Comment: please i need an answer

Comment: Men Thnaks! you are amazing!!